# How to set the font type globally

Tags: fonts

I am referring to these [Font typefaces](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces) from Overleaf for reference.

So, my question is how to set the font type globally.

Example 1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgbonum}

\begin{document}
test sentence 1.

test sentence 2.

test sentence 3.
\end{document}
```

Here is my result, the font is all successfully set to TEX Gyre Bonum.

[image]

Example 2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}
test sentence 1.

test sentence 2.

test sentence 3.
\end{document}
```

Here is my result, unfortunately, the font is all set to the default font Computer Modern Roman.

[image]

To set all the font to helvet, I have to do something like this:

Example 3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}
{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont test sentence 1.}

{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont test sentence 2.}

{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont test sentence 3.}
\end{document}
```

Here is my result, the font is all set to helvet.

[image]

So my question is, to be specific, when using `\usepackage{tgbonum}`, font will be set globally. However, when using `\usepackage{helvet}`, font is not changed at all. Why would it happen? How to set the font globally for helvet?

Comment: helvet changes the sans serif family. If you want to change the rmfamily to sans serif you can use \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}.

Comment: The package `helvet` does not change the default text font family from
`roman`. Try `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`.

Comment: so my understanding is, currently, the default font family is ```\rmfamily``` but ```helvet``` belongs to the ```\sffamily```.  So if I want to use ```helvet``` globally, I need to change the default font family first. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `phv` as the default font, just issue the instruction

```
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
```

after running `\usepackage{helvet}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault

\begin{document}
test sentence 1.

test sentence 2.

test sentence 3.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So my understanding is, currently, the default font family is ```\rmfamily``` but ```helvet``` belongs to the ```\sffamily```.  So if I want to use ```helvet``` globally, I need to change the default font family first. Is that correct?

Comment: @liaoming999 - That's (essentially) correct for most document classes: The default text font family is "serif" or "roman"; to make the sans-serif font the default font family, it's necessary to tell LaTeX about this, e.g., by issuing the instruction `\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault`.

Comment: +1 I'd suggest `tgheros`. It's a basically a clone of `helvet` but with full `T1` and `TS1` support.

Comment: @campa - I agree. The set of glyphs provided by the `helvet` package is fairly minimal.