# When to use the command `\renewcommand\familydefault\xxdefault`

Tags: fonts

This is a follow-up question of my previous question [How to set the font type globally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700628/how-to-set-the-font-type-globally/700629?noredirect=1#comment1741884_700629).

To use helvet globally, I have to use the command `\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault`. So when I am using the following code:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
```

The font is successfully changed to Helvet.

In my understanding, currently, the default font family is `\rmfamily` and helvet belongs to `\sffamily`. Therefore, I need to declare the default font family to Sans Serif (i.e., `\sffamily`).

However, according to [Sans Serif Fonts](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html), there are other fonts which belong to Sans Serif too. For example, Arev. When I am trying to use the font Arev globally, all I need to do is to use the following code:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{arev}
```

The font is successfully changed to Arev globally.

My question is, Arev belongs to the Sans Serif. Why don't I need to declare the default font family to Sans Serif (i.e., no need to use `\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault`)? When is the right time to use the command `\renewcommand\familydefault\xxdefault` (`\xxdefault` can be `\sfdefault`, `\rmdefault` or `\ttdefault`)?

However,

Answer (score 5):

Every package handles things differently. Some font packages only set the font for the serif family or for the sans familiy, others, line the `arev` package, set the font for both families.

For example, the `helvet` package (being a part of the `psfonts` package, so the following can be found in `psfonts.sty`) essentially only does:

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
```

That is, it sets the `sf` family to the font `phv` (which is Helvetica) and that's it. It does not set the `rm` family to anything, so it stays the default.

In the code of the `arev` package on the other hand, you will find the following lines (in `arevtext.sty`):

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{fav}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fav}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{fvm}
```

This means that the package sets the font `fav` for the `rm` family as well as for the `sf` family. And this is why you don't need to set `\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault` after having loaded this package.

So the answer to your question is: It depends on whether the package sets this font for you already or not. For this to know, you should look into the documentation of the package (or you can just try what it does by loading it). Some packages even provide an option to set which font families they change.